# How Can I set moving object as Marker in Google Maps API using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firebase-realtime-database

Recently I developed Mobile tracking Android Application. In the Android Application, it sends the user's latitude and longitude values to the Firebase database every 10 seconds. The number of users (who used our app) appear in google maps with markers. The problem is that when the Firebase is updated the markers also refreshed, but it blinks. I need to show them as moving markers. When the Firebase gives a response, the marker will also need to change position according to Firebase data. But in my application Markers are not working properly.

TrackUser.html :

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var map;         
  var markers = [];
  initMap();
             function initMap() {
                
             if (navigator.geolocation) {
               $("#map").html("<img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/loading.gif' />");
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

                       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                      zoom: 12,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   });
               } 
              );
             }
                 }
  
  // Get a reference to the database service
    firebase.database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot) {
 console.log(snapshot.val());
  var arr = Object.values(snapshot.val().users);
  setMapOnAll(null);
  markers = [];  
   for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

      var splitVals = arr[i].lat.split(" ");

      var name=splitVals[0];
      var latitu = splitVals[1];
      var longitu =splitVals[2];  
  var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitu+","+longitu+"&sensor=true";
  $.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",    
     async: false
  })
  .done(function(resultdata, textStatus, jqXHR){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitu, longitu),
              map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            
            var i;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
             return function() {
               infowindow.setContent("Name : "+name+"<br>"+"Location : "+resultdata.results[1].formatted_address);
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
             }
           })(marker, i));
             
             infowindow.setContent("Name : "+name+"<br>"+"Location : "+resultdata.results[2].formatted_address);
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
  })
 }

    }); 
  
    function setMapOnAll(map) {
     console.log("Set map is to empty state ");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
      }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Set markers on map only once and in when at every 10s firebase update value, just set Lat and Lon on map so you will see markers are moving on map

Comment: Thank you Sir  @yogen darji , I just Confused. Can You explain in my code!!!